# UIAlertView and UIActionSheet buttonClicked - EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, uialertview, exc-bad-access, uiactionsheet, crashlytics

I've received two crash reports on Crashlytics, with similar logs, one for an `UIAlertView` and one for an `UIActionSheet`:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xa0000008

0    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 15
1    UIKit   -[UIAlertView(Private) _buttonClicked:] + 296
2    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 72
3    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
4    UIKit   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
5    UIKit   -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 502
6    UIKit   -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 488
7    UIKit   -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 524
8    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 380
9    UIKit   _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6154
10   GraphicsServices    _PurpleEventCallback + 590
11   GraphicsServices    PurpleEventCallback + 34
12 ...   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
```

I'm using ARC and in my code I  alloc/init alert views and action sheets in view controllers setting delegates to `self`.  I can't find the source of the problem, any suggestions?

This is an example in `SomeViewController.m`:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Are you sure?", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Continue",nil) destructiveButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Yes", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil];
            actionSheet.delegate = self;
            [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

end the I implement `(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

Comment: Is this when you click a button? It could not be connected to a real method

Comment: it happens, it seems, when you click on a button or the alert view or the action sheet

Answer (score 2):

The Finest way to find this kind of bug Use the `NSZombieEnabled` environment variable.cause of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is from trying to access released objects.[Review this](http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/)

Answer (score 0):

You can debug to see at which statement the exception occurs

1. Click on 'show breakpoint navigator' on left side panel
2. Click + button on down of panel
3. Add exception breakpoint
4. Done pop up

Now it will shows exception statement

Comment: Crashlytics is reporting me this crashes, some users are experiencing that, I can't reproduce them